# ScrollPane translúcido en JavaFX

Tags: javafx

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el fondo del contenido de un `ScrollPane` deje entrever lo que hay debajo? Con `setOpacity()` también se vuelven translúcidos los controles contenidos en el `ScrollPane` y lo que pretendo es que sólo sea el fondo semitransparente. He probado con CSS: -`fx-background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);` pero el fondo continúa opaco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error común es intentar aplicar la opacidad directamente al `ScrollPane` y no a su `viewport`. La solución en CSS es:

```
#panelScroll > .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.5)};
}
```

Y en código java:

```
panelScroll.lookup(".viewport").setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.05);");
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero necesitas agregar eso:

```
.scroll-pane > .viewport {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Y ahora ya puedes hacer el `ScrollPane` transparente con esto:

```
.scroll-pane {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Espero haber ayudado.

Referencias:

- [ScrollPanes in JavaFX 8 always have gray background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952531/scrollpanes-in-javafx-8-always-have-gray-background)
- [CSS styling of ScrollPanes broken in JavaFX 8?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3538169)