# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el fondo del contenido de un ScrollPane sea transparente?

Tags: javafx

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el fondo del contenido de un ScrollPane sea transparente?
He probado con:

- `setOpacity()`,
- con css

  ```
  .scroll-pane > .viewport {
      -fx-background-color: transparent;
  }
  ```

  y

  ```
  .scroll-pane {
     -fx-background-color: transparent;
  }
  ```
- Además con `panelScroll.lookup(".viewport").setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.05);");`

Y nada funciona.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [ScrollPane translúcido en JavaFX](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4220/scrollpane-transl%c3%bacido-en-javafx)

Comment: El problema es que las soluciones en la pregunta ScrollPane translúcido en JavaFX no me funcionaron.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a cambiar directamente el atributo opacity desde Css?. A veces he tenido ese problema y alternando entre estos valores me ha ido bien.

```
    .scroll-pane {
       opacity: 0.9 ;//Valor de 0 a 1
    }
```